# Ruby Performance: Chaining selects vs AND-ing predicates?

Tags: ruby, performance

If I want to select all elements of an array `arr` satisfying both predicates `p_1` and `p_2`, then I have two options for implementation:

Option 1:

```
arr.select{|x| x.p_1}.select{|x| x.p_2}
```

Option 2:

```
arr.select{|x| x.p_1 && x.p_2}
```

Is there a significant difference between the two? In my use case the predicate `p_1` reduces the list much more than `p_2`, and `p_2` is more expensive than `p_1`. So I suspect putting `p_1` before `p_2` makes it quicker. But do either of the options above make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean by difference? Speed, the order of execution, or something else ?

Comment: Option 1 creates a temporary array containing the elements satisfying `p_1` and then filters that (smaller) array again, returning elements which (also) satisfy `p_2`. Option 2 on the other hand does both checks at once (`&&` short-circuits), thus eliminating the need for a temporary array. Unless `arr` is really huge, I think it's more a matter of style / preference / readability.

Comment: @Stefan +1, in both situations costly `p2` will be executed the same amount of times. Each `select` will create an intermediate array, so this has some overhead, at least from a memory perspective. If you are willing to chain a number of this kind of filters and you want to keep this "chain" readability you could think of using transducers (if there are in Ruby ^^).

Comment: https://medium.com/@baweaver/understanding-transducers-in-ruby-209766372c39

Comment: @Viktor I tagged this as performance, but I guess that's not really what I mean. It's obviously a very small change and in ordinary usage the difference in speeds will be miniscule. I knew that the `&&` would stop immediately if `p_1` was false, and therefore the number of predicate executions was the same. But they're clearly not *exactly* the same. So I suppose I was just curious to see exactly what they did differently, and whether this had any important consequences. It's possible that Stefan's comment answers the question, I did not know in advance what the answer would be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already aware of both the performance characteristics your predicates and the shape of your data, which is great!

Is there a difference? Simply put, yes -- the evaluation order is different:

```rb
# Option 1
arr[0].p_1
arr[1].p_1
arr[2].p_1
...
arr[n].p_1
arr[0].p_2
arr[1].p_2
arr[2].p_2
...
arr[n].p_2
```

versus

```rb
# Option 2
arr[0].p_1
arr[0].p_2
arr[1].p_1
arr[1].p_2
arr[2].p_1
arr[2].p_2
...
arr[n].p_1
arr[n].p_2
```

Now, *does it matter*? That depends on very situational and contextual side-effects. Just as examples, let's explore a few scenarios:

### Blocking, Buffered I/O

Suppose the reason `p_2` was much more expensive is because it does some I/O like write to disk. It may be the case that this output operation is buffered, and while the Ruby runtime may return from the `p_2` call, the output is still flushing by the time `p_2` is called again, blocking it.

In this particular case, Option 2 is faster because `p_1` computation can continue in the interim between the `p_2` calls that block each other.

### Cache Misses

Suppose the reason `p_1` is fast is because its computation can be cached. Let's also suppose that calling `p_2` disrupts that cache somehow in a way that make subsequent `p_1` calls get cache misses:

- maybe it also adds to the cache, and the cache fills up, evicting values
- maybe the cache is time-evicted, and the cached data is evicted between `p_1` calls because `p_2` just takes too long

In this particular case, Option 1 is faster because the grouped `p_1` calls are able to take advantage of the cache.

### Sharing Limited Memory

Suppose both `p_1` and `p_2` calls require a lot of memory. Perhaps by interleaving them, resources needed by both have to be made readily available the entire time, hitting the memory limits of the system, hurting performance.

In this case, Option 1 is faster because once all `p_1` calls are done, the memory used to hold its resources can be freed for use by the later `p_2` calls.